How to delete alert sound in windows forms C# textbox?
I was working in windows forms, and I wanted to do the Action() when enter is pressed. And it work's but there was an alert sound.
This is my code:
namespace PasswordManager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void EnterPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "" && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) // if Enter is pressed
            {
                Action();
            }
        }

        private void Action()
        {
        }
    }
}

How to fix this???

Use this code in the EnterPressed() event.
e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
e.Handled = true;


You don't need to set e.Handled when you have already set e.SuppressKeyPress, because it's the same thing

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
